# python c api with multiple file

Tags: c++, python-3.x, python-c-api, c-header

While writing python c api, I wanted to separate it into multiple files. 
So, I separated the files (module.cpp and support.cpp) and wrote the function declarations in the separate files (support.h).

But how to write `setup.py`?

```sh
├── cpp
│   ├── module.cpp
│   ├── support.cpp
│   └── support.h
├── setup.py
└── tsmodule
    └── __init__.py
```

module.cpp

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "support.h"
// int bar(int x){
//     return x + 1;
// }

PyObject* foo(PyObject *, PyObject* args) {
    int x;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &x);
    char str[100];
    sprintf(str, "%d\n", bar(x));
    return PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(str, strlen(str));
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    { "foo", (PyCFunction)foo, METH_O, nullptr },
    { nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr }
};
static PyModuleDef module = {PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "module", " ", 0, methods};
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_module() {return PyModule_Create(&module);}
```

support.cpp

```c
#include "support.h"
int bar(int x){return x + 1;}
```

support.h

```c
#ifndef SUPPORT_H
#define SUPPORT_H
int bar(int);
#endif
```

tsmodule/__init__.py

```py
from .module import foo
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Command, Extension
NAME = 'tsmodule'
ext_modules = [Extension('tsmodule.module', sources = ['cpp/module.cpp'])]
setup(
    name=NAME,
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests", "*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*"]),
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

testing code (expected output: b'133\n')

```py
import tsmodule
print(tsmodule.foo((132,)))
```

it return

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mine/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tsmodule/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .module import foo
ImportError: /home/mine/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tsmodule/module.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Z3bari
```

Comment: You did not compiled the support.cpp file. I'm not familiar with this setup.py stuff, but you should pass the support.cpp to the sources...

Comment: @simre's advice solved the problem. This question was trying to implement a minimal content to reproduce, but there were additional problems with the actual code. I was using the template in the header file, and after removing all parameter packing, I was able to execute successfully. `template<typename... Ts> int foo(Ts...);` -> `int foo(int *);`

Comment: If it solved your problem, please add the answer how you did that, so if someone else will have the same problem, he/she will see that there is a solution for that.